# Using foreign key in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, foreign-keys, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have two tables:

1. A **jobs** table with 3 fields: `id`, `client_id`, `name`.
2. A **clients** table with 2 fields: `id`, `name`.

Using Angular 1.5, I'm iterating over the jobs:

```
controller('JobsController', ['$scope', 'Job', 'Client', function($scope, Job, Client) {
    $scope.jobs = Job.query();
    $scope.clients = Client.query();
}]);
```

**HTML:**

```
<tr ng-repeat="job in jobs">
    <td>
        {{clients[job.client_id].name}}
    </td>
    <td>
        {{job.name}}
    </td>
</tr>
```

In the HTML the first column should be the client name. As it is, this isn't working, because `$scope.clients` is an array of objects that look a bit like this:

`[{'id':4, 'name':'test_name'}, {'id':7, 'name':'another client'}]`

Is there a way to pick from this `clients` array by `id`, in my `ng-repeat` loop?

`$scope.jobs` looks like:

`[{'id':100, 'client_id': 4, 'name': 'a job'}, ...]`

Comment: how does $scope.jobs  looks like ..?

Comment: Added example `$scope.jobs`.

Comment: Your problem is that your clients in the $scope.client array are classified by any order you decided in your Back-end. 

What you are doing here is taking the (job.client_id)st client of your clients array, which have nothing to see with the client with the job.client_id client. 

Your solution only works if a client has NEVER be deleted and clients_id are actually the natural numbers in the right order, which is not good.

Create a function to get the right client in the array then call it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To begin with, it may be easier to do the join on the server side, to where your `$scope.jobs` would look more like:

```
[
{
    'id': 100,
    'name': 'a job',
    'client': {
        'id': 4
        'name': 'test_name'
    }
} 
...
]
```

If you need to do it on the front end, what I would do is add a method to your controller to get the client for a specified job. Something like this:

```
$scope.getClientName = function(job) {
    //to prevent errors if $scope.clients is not loaded yet
    if (!$scope.clients) {
        return;
    }

    for (var c = 0; c < $scope.clients.length; c++) {
        var client = $scope.clients[c];
        if (client.id = job.client_id) {
            return client.name;
        }
    }
}
```

Then instead of `{{clients[job.client_id].name}}` call your function and pass in the `job`:

```
{{getClientName(job)}}
```

Comment: Isn't it better to join the two arrays after success callbacks?
Because a function expression is will execute the digestcylcle multiple times, so the performance will be decreased,won't it?

Comment: I believe the function wouldn't actually be called until there is some data in the `$scope.jobs` array, since that is what is being ng-repeated over. It may be a good idea to add a condition at the beginning of the function though, in case `jobs` get loaded before `clients`. Something like `if (!$scope.clients) return;`

Comment: @ThomasZoé totally agree. For sure a merge should be made only on initilization (a **single** time).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in front end as below

```
$scope.clients = [{'id':1, 'name':'test_name'}, {'id':4, 'name':'another client'}];
$scope.jobs = [{'id':100, 'client_id': 4, 'name': 'a job4'}, {'id':100, 'client_id': 1, 'name': 'a job1'}, {'id':100, 'client_id': 24, 'name': 'a job24'}];
function fillJobsByClient(jobs, client){
    for(var i=0; i<jobs.length; i++){
        if(jobs[i].client_id == client.id){
            jobs[i].client = client;
            delete jobs[i].client_id;
        }
    }
}

$scope.clients.forEach(function(client){
    fillJobsByClient($scope.jobs, client);


});

console.log($scope.jobs);
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is late, but I figured it might help point someone else on the right direction. This is how you could do it on the front end, you should load your array OnInit, then use an if statement to select the correct detail field.

```js
<tr *ngFor='let j of jobs'>    
  <td>
    <div *ngFor='let c of clients'>
      <div *ngIf='c.id== j.client_id'>{{j.name}}</div>
    </div>
 </td>
</tr>
```